# Excel VBA Web Scraping IE NAVIGATE method Works Vs MSXML2.XMLHTTP60 not Working

Tags: html, excel, vba, web-scraping

I am trying to pull the one parameter from NSE WEB SITE,
The url is https://www1.nseindia.com/live_market/dynaContent/live_watch/get_quote/GetQuoteFO.jsp?underlying=INDUSINDBK&instrument=FUTSTK&type=-&strike=-&expiry=30APR2020

I am able to scrape what ever i want using IE.Navigate(Internet explorer) method (Which opens the browser and get the data),but this takes long time,i want the results to be extracted fast,so i decided to go with "MSXML2.XMLHTTP60" method,when i try,the response text,it returns internal server error

Here below i have given my both the codes,please help me for scraping the data in MSXML2.XMLHTTP60 method

- Working Code but takes time

  ```
  Sub NSE_Data_Pull()

      Application.EnableEvents = False
      Application.ScreenUpdating = False
      Application.DisplayAlerts = False

      Dim ie As New InternetExplorer
      Set ie = CreateObject("InternetExplorer.Application")

      ie.Visible = True
      ie.navigate "https://www1.nseindia.com/live_market/dynaContent/live_watch/get_quote/GetQuoteFO.jsp?underlying=INFY&instrument=FUTSTK&type=-&strike=-&expiry=30APR2020#"
      Do

      DoEvents
      Loop Until ie.readyState = READYSTATE_COMPLETE

      Dim doc As HTMLDocument
      Set doc = ie.document

      doc.Focus
      ActiveSheet.Cells(2, 3) = doc.getElementById("pchangeinOpenInterest").innerText

      ie.Quit
      ie.Visible = True
      Set doc = Nothing
      Set ie = Nothing

      Application.DisplayAlerts = True
      Application.ScreenUpdating = True
      Application.EnableEvents = True

  End Sub
  ```
- Need help here only: response text returns internal server error - Fast Method

  ```
  Sub NSE_Data_Pull()

      Dim xhr As MSXML2.XMLHTTP60, html As MSHTML.HTMLDocument
      Set xhr = New MSXML2.XMLHTTP60
      Set html = New MSHTML.HTMLDocument

      With xhr
          .Open "GET", "https://www1.nseindia.com/live_market/dynaContent/live_watch/get_quote/GetQuoteFO.jsp?underlying=BEL&instrument=FUTSTK&type=-&strike=-&expiry=30APR2020#", False
          .send
           html.body.innerHTML = StrConv(.responseBody, vbUnicode)
      End With

      Debug.Print html.body.innerHTML
     ActiveSheet.Cells(2, 3).Value = html.getElementById("pchangeinOpenInterest").innerHTML
  End Sub
  ```

Comment: Are you sure you want to use a GET request? Might need to be a POST

Comment: I checked page response in network tab,it shows only the GET response,so thats why i used GET

Answer (score 0):

This code runs fine for me. It uses both, XMLHTTP and MSHTML, so there are no side effects from components:

```vb
Sub xxx()
    Dim xhr As New MSXML2.XMLHTTP60
    Dim html As New MSHTML.HTMLDocument

    With xhr
        .Open "GET", "https://www1.nseindia.com/live_market/dynaContent/live_watch/get_quote/GetQuoteFO.jsp?underlying=BEL&instrument=FUTSTK&type=-&strike=-&expiry=30APR2020#", False
        .send
        'Debug.Print StrConv(.responseBody, vbUnicode)
        html.body.innerHTML = StrConv(.responseBody, vbUnicode)

    End With
    Debug.Print html.body.innerHTML

    Set xhr = Nothing
End Sub
```

Probably the problem is not on XMLHTTP. Do you have any HTTP proxy servers there? If IE works but XMLHTTP not, this means IE uses system settings for http proxy, but XMLHTTP does not. So you should initialise it with your proxy. It has the setProxy method.
By the way, if the object is declared as new you don't have to initialize it once again with CreateObject:

```vb
    Dim ie As New InternetExplorer
    Set ie = CreateObject("InternetExplorer.Application")
```